# Bijective function and vector space mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$E$ and $E'$ are finite dimension vector spaces.

I need to prove that if $f$ is a linear mapping from $E$ to $E'$ then it is a bijective function if and only if the mappings from a basis of $E$ using f generate a basis of $E'$.

Assuming $f$ is a bijective function, the mapped vectors using f are both linearly independent and span $E'$. How can I prove that $dimE$ = $dimE'$? I mean, I need to show that the correspondence one-to-one generates basis of $E'$ using the basis vectors of $E$.

Comment: If you are working in FDVS. Suppose you have $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_n\}$ as a basis for $E$ and with $f$ being a bijection you have shown that $\{f(v_1), f(v_2), \ldots , f(v_n)\}$ is *a basis* for $E'$, then by the fact that all bases for a finite dimensional vector space have the same number of elements, we also get $\text{dim}(E')=n$.

Comment: Every bijection can be considered a relabeling. Watch which labels are assigned to the  basis vectors by the mapping and the result becomes a matter of notation.

Comment: @AnuragA I see now, the fact that it implies that there is always a one-to-one relation from $E$ to $E'$ then $E'$ necessarily has the same number of vectors as $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dimensions since the spaces are not given to be finite dimensional. Let $(x_i)$ be  basis for $E$ and $y \in E'$. Since $f$ is surjective there exists $x \in E$ such that $y=f(x)$. Now write $x$ as  a linear combination of $x_i$'s and use linearilty of $f$ to conclude that $y=f(x)$ is  a linear combination of $f(x_i)$'s. This proves that $(f(x_i))$ spans $E'$. Since they are also linearly independent they form a basis for $E'$.

Comment: That makes sense, but I was referring to finite dimension vector spaces. I'll edit the O.P